# Deleting roles with Asp.net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can someone describe to me just how you delete roles with asp.net identity.  I tried the following, but it did not work and I received a **Specified Method is not supported** error:

```
public async Task DeleteRole(string role)
    {
        // delete role
        var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new Context());
        await roleStore.DeleteAsync(new IdentityRole(role));


    }
```

Not sure if this is referring to something with my async logic, or specifically with asp.net identity itself.  Nevertheless can someone demonstrate to me how to make this work correctly.  There is virtually no documentation available on the new identity system for asp.net at this time.

Comment: What is you role provider? It is generally specified in web config.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Identity context (IdentityDbContext) contains the role store. So you would (assuming AppDb is your context):

```
var role = AppDb.Roles.Where(d => d.Name == "my role name").FirstOrDefault();
AppDb.Roles.Remove(role);
AppDb.SaveChanges();
```

You basically treat it as a normal EntityFramework DbSet, it's inherited from the IdentityDbContext.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my issue. I've been on this for the last two days.  Although I'm satisfied with this solution, what's the deal with the RoleStore DeleteAsync method? Is it meant to be used in the way that I used it?

Comment: Not quite sure TBH. The documentation on the new ASP.NET Identity is abysmal and a depressing effort at helping us truly get us on the right track. It's more of a trial and error & search and find method to get this to work.

Comment: You are using the API correctly. If you look at DeleteAsync with a decompiler you'll see it throws a NotImplementedException, and so does not provide the ability to delete a role!

Answer (score 9):

I know that is an old question, but I've tried a way that doesn't touch store (or `DbContext`) directly.

> I've used it in ASP.NET Core 2.1

```
var role = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(roleName);
var result = await _roleManager.DeleteAsync(role);
```

needless to say that it:

- delete role that assigned to user -> `AspNetUserRoles`
- delete role's claims -> `AspNetRoleClaims`
- delete role itself -> `AspNetRoles`